# Spring BeanCreationException Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea, javabeans

I have to make an Rest API in Java using Spring framework, when I run it with IntelliJ, everything is ok and got no error. But when I create a jar file and execute it, my project does not work anymore because of this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private eu.epitech.jungeryazdi.repository.NewsRepository eu.epitech.jungeryazdi.controller.NewsController.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [eu.epitech.jungeryazdi.repository.NewsRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at ...
... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [eu.epitech.jungeryazdi.repository.NewsRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[jweb.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[jweb.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[jweb.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[jweb.jar:na]
... 19 common frames omitted
```

So here are my files :
**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JwebApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(JwebApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    return factory;
  }
}
```

**NewsRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface NewsRepository extends CrudRepository<News, Long> {

Iterable<News>  findByTitle(@Param("title") String title);

}
```

**NewsController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/news")
public class NewsController {

@Autowired(required = true)
private NewsRepository repository;

@Autowired(required = true)
private UserRepository user_repository;

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity getNews(@RequestParam(value = "id", defaultValue = "-1") long id,
                          @RequestParam(value = "title", defaultValue = "") String title) {

   ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public HttpEntity sendNewsToSubscribers(@RequestParam(value = "title") String title,
                                        @RequestParam(value = "message") String message,
                                        @RequestParam(value = "token") String token) {

    ...
  }

}
```

**News.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NEWS")
public class News {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "TITLE")
private String title;

@Column(name = "MESSAGE")
private String message;

@Column(name = "DATE")
private Date date;

public News(String ti, String mess) {
    title = ti;
    message = mess;
    date = new Date();
}

public News() { }

...

}
```

Comment: I am not professional at Spring, but what I am thinking is that whether you include all required class files in the jar? Because the error said "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [eu.epitech.jungeryazdi.repository.NewsRepository] found for dependency"

Comment: Can you share the NewsRepository implementation of your code.

Comment: @Mohit I have no implementation of NewsRepository, I extend from CrudRepository, which provides me needed methods.

Comment: Just give a @ComponentScan("<package of NewsRepository>") on top of your JwebApplication class. It will work.

Comment: It runs but now, when I access to localhost:8080 I have : http://imgur.com/SfpooXZ

Comment: This doesn't work in IntelliJ either -- at least, not as it's posted here. You need to follow Mohit's comment/answer above to make this work at all. If you have it working in idea, then you're doing something weird -- stop it ;)

Comment: Post your pom and also remove the `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean from your configuration. Spring Boot does al that for you (and this might influence with the one configured already). Also make sure you have the correct dependencies in your classpath and that the `Application` class is in one of the root packages so that it scans all packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing a little thing, I didn't generate the .jar with IntelliJ but with maven using :

```
mvn package
```